# How to copy range format to chart data table? Google Spreadsheets

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to use script to make an png of seleced range of spreadsheet. So far I create png but it has custom formatting. I want to make an exact copy of selected range.

```
  function savePNG(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = ss.getRange("A1:F20");
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var fileName = "Quotation for " + ss.getRange("Sheet1!E5").getValue() + ".png"

  const [header, ...values] = range.getDisplayValues();
  const table = Charts.newDataTable();
  header.forEach(e => table.addColumn(Charts.ColumnType.STRING, e));
  values.forEach(e => table.addRow(e));

  
  const image = Charts.newTableChart().setDataTable(table.build()).setDimensions(800, 800).setOption('alternatingRowStyle', false).build().getBlob().setName(fileName);
  var file = DriveApp.createFile(image); 

  const htmlOutput = HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutput('<p>Click to open <p><a href="' + file.getUrl() + '" target="_blank">' + fileName + '</a></p></p>')
    .setWidth(300)
    .setHeight(80)
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Link to png')

}
```

Here is an example what I get and what I want:
[current result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjb8U.png),
[desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsQNF.png)